# Using VBA / AHK to highlight the most recent email in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, autohotkey

Within Outlook, in the central pane of Outlook one can see a table of emails in the currently selected folder. I would like to highlight, but not open, the most recently received of these.  I'm doing this in AHK so the code looks a little odd, but it’s basically VBA.

```
OlApp := ComObjActive("Outlook.Application")
ActiveExplorer := OlApp.ActiveExplorer
MyCurrentFolder:= OlApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
MyItems := MyCurrentFolder.Items
MyItems.Sort("[Received]", true)
MailItem:=MyItems.GetFirst
ActiveExplorer.ClearSelection
ActiveExplorer.AddToSelection(MailItem)
```

However: 
1) it doesn't run at all when the folder is set to View > “Show as Conversations”
2) although it does highlight the most recent email, it does not give that email keyboard focus; e.g. if you try to use the keyboard down arrows to select the next email in the list you will find that the keyboard's focus is on a different email.
3) MailItem seems to get the most recent email in ANY folder, not the current folder.

Any suggestions to improve on these shortcomings would be gratefully received.